# Blank fragment is being displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-room

### **Expected action:**:

When user clicks on the "**Add to favourites button**" the book will be added to the local database and a toast will appear saying that the book has been added to the favourites . Here I have used Room Persistance library. Then on clicking the favourite fragment in the menu drawer, the favourites page displaying the favourite book should appear.

**Error:**
the toast appears when I click on the add to favourites button but
The favourite fragment page is blank.

**What i have done:**
The required part  description activity code is as follows :#

```
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@DescriptionActivity)
        val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v1/book/get_book/"
    
        val jsonParams = JSONObject()
        jsonParams.put("book_id", bookId)
        if(ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(this@DescriptionActivity)) {
    
            val jsonRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, jsonParams, Response.Listener {
                    try {
    
                        val success = it.getBoolean("success")
                        if (success) {
                            val bookJsonObject = it.getJSONObject("book_data")
                            progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
    
                            val bookImageUrl = bookJsonObject.getString("image")
    
                            Picasso.get().load(bookJsonObject.getString("image"))
                                .error(R.drawable.default_book).into(imgBookImage)
                            txtBookName.text = bookJsonObject.getString("name")
                            txtBookAuthor.text = bookJsonObject.getString("author")
                            txtBookPrice.text = bookJsonObject.getString("price")
                            txtBookRating.text = bookJsonObject.getString("rating")
                            txtBookDesc.text = bookJsonObject.getString("description")
    
                            val bookEntity = BookEntity(
                                bookId?.toInt() as Int,
                                txtBookName.text.toString(),
                                txtBookAuthor.text.toString(),
                                txtBookPrice.text.toString(),
                                txtBookRating.text.toString(),
                                txtBookDesc.text.toString(),
                                bookImageUrl
                            )
    
                            val checkFav = DBAsyncTask(applicationContext,bookEntity,1).execute()
                            val isFav = checkFav.get()
    
                            if(isFav){
                                btnAddToFav.text = "remove from Favourites"
                                val favColor = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,R.color.colorFavourite)
                                btnAddToFav.setBackgroundColor(favColor)
                            }else{
                                btnAddToFav.text = "add to favourites"
                                val nofav = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorPrimary)
                                btnAddToFav.setBackgroundColor(nofav)
                            }
    
                            btnAddToFav.setOnClickListener {
                                if(!DBAsyncTask(applicationContext,bookEntity,1).execute().get()) {
                                    val async = DBAsyncTask(applicationContext, bookEntity, 2).execute()
                                    val result = async.get()
                                    if (result) {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            this@DescriptionActivity,
                                            "book added to favourites",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                        ).show()
    
                                    btnAddToFav.text = "remove from favourites"
                                    val favColor = ContextCompat.getColor(
                                        applicationContext,
                                        R.color.colorFavourite
                                    )
                                    btnAddToFav.setBackgroundColor(favColor)
    
                                } else{
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            this@DescriptionActivity,
                                            "some error occurred",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                        ).show()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    val async = DBAsyncTask(applicationContext,bookEntity,3).execute()
                                    val result = async.get()
                                    if(result){
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            this@DescriptionActivity,
                                            "book removed from favourites",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                        ).show()
    
                                        btnAddToFav.text = "add to favourites"
                                        val nofav = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorPrimary)
                                        btnAddToFav.setBackgroundColor(nofav)
    
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            this@DescriptionActivity,
                                            "some error occurred",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                        ).show()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@DescriptionActivity as Context,
                                "some error has occurred",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
```

### **This is the asyncTask code:**

````
 

        class DBAsyncTask(context: Context,val bookEntity: BookEntity, val mode : Int) : 
           AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>()
        {
        
            /*
            mode 1: check db if book is in favourite or not
            mode 2: save the book into db as favourite
            mode 3: remove the favourite book
             */
        
            val db = Room.databaseBuilder(context,BookDatabase::class.java, "book-db").build()
        
            override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Boolean {
                when(mode){
                    1-> {
                        val book: BookEntity? = db.bookDao().getBookById(bookEntity.book_id.toString())
                        db.close()
                        return book != null
                    }
        
                    2->{
                        db.bookDao().insertBook(bookEntity)
                        db.close()
                        return true
                    }
        
                    3->{
        
                        db.bookDao().deleteBook(bookEntity)
                        db.close()
                        return true
        
                    }
        
                }
        
        
                return false
            }
        
        }
    
    ```
````

Comment: Is the information saved in the Database? you can extract sqlite file and browse it tabledata.

Comment: Processing in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask) is asynchronous, i.e. does not execute immediately.  The result of the processing cannot be used ( for example: `result = async.get()`),  in the statement directly following call to `execute()`.